# Symfony 2 Functional Testing external URL

Tags: url, symfony, cross-domain, phpunit, web-crawler

Whatever I do, I always get a

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for [...]"

in `$crawler->text()`, when I try to request an external URL with `$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://anotherdomain.com');`.

I want to do that because I'm using another virtualHost to render some pages with Symfony 1.2 and some others with Symfony 2.3.

I also tried to

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array('HTTP_HOST' => 'anotherdomain.com'));
$client->followRedirects(true);
```

But it's always trying to render it whithin Symfony 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible, because `$client` actually doesn't send any http request (you may notice that when you try run your "functional" test with www server disabled - they still should work). Instead of that it simulates http request and run normal Symfony's dispatching.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected !